# Laravel 5.1 csrftoken curl from paypal

Tags: php, laravel, curl, paypal

How i Can add or somethink do with csrftoken when paypal send post on my website.
My error code: 
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53.

Here code:

```
    public function getPaypal(Request $request)
   {

    $uri = $request->all();

    if(isset($uri['tx']))
    {

      $pp_hostname = "www.sandbox.paypal.com"; // Change to www.sandbox.paypal.com to test against sandbox
      // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
      $req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

      $tx_token = $uri['tx'];
      $auth_token = "EHNebv....e";
      $req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
      //set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
      //if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
      $res = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to completely disable the middleware just go to VerifyCrsfToken file in app\Http\Middle then edit the protected array $except and include and entry of the route paypal is posting to.

```
protected $except = [
    /paypal/data,


];
```

Answer (score 4):

According to Laravel Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection.

> **Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection**
>
> Sometimes you may wish to exclude a set of URIs from CSRF protection.
>   For example, if you are using **Stripe** to process payments and are
>   utilizing their webhook system, you will need to exclude your webhook
>   handler route from Laravel's CSRF protection.
>
> You may exclude URIs by adding them to the $except property of the
>   VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'paypal/*',
    ];
}
```

Let me know if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

`TokenMismatchException` is a Laravel error, not PayPal. With every `POST` request, you need to send a `_token` value through with it.

If you are sending this through a form, simply echo `csrf_field()` into your form template.

If you are sending the request from something other than Laravel, you can disable the CSRF protection on that route. Read more about Middleware here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware

Read more about it here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection