# RESTful API with Userfrosting

Tags: php, laravel, slim, userfrosting

I'm using UserFrosting to manage users with `PHP`, in my `API` and I want to use the login function in controller with POST method.

When i call the login function it return me as response

> The CSRF code was invalid or not provided.

I still cannot get the **csrf_token**

Any idea?

Comment: Add `{{ csrf_field() }}` to your html form

Comment: is it working for you ??

Comment: i'm calling the api from outside page php and i havn't the twig

Comment: Is it an ajax call ??

Comment: no it's in curl php

Comment: Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32764606/4881811) !

Comment: Which framework are you using? This post has both tags `laravel` and `slim`

Comment: usingFrosting include slimFramwork and laravel orm eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a UserFrosting Sprinkle that implements JWT authentication: https://github.com/x00x70/tokeniser

Join us in [chat](https://chat.userfrosting.com) if you have any questions about its use!

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an API (either for it to be consumed by an webplatform or mobile app) I belive it's better to have a different kind of authentication, namely, JWT authentication. In Laravel you have Passport to handle this Authentication with ease.
I'm not sure how userFroasting uses laravel but if laravel version is above 5.3 you can use it.

If it isn't there's always the option of making a costum JWT authentication.

Here is the latest documentation for Passport https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport.

Comment: i choose to work with userFrosting cause it's complete application user-admin. so BackOffice and Frontoffice already done!